# Getting undefine trying to get the ObjectId of a Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

i'm making a voting system for a Message Board app using Backbone.
The problem here is that when i try to get the objectId of an object and set it as a "rel" attribute in a certain tag the attribute is set as "undefined" .

```
<% if(models.length>0) {
                    _.each(models, function(value, key, list) {%>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= value.attributes.username %></td>
                        <td><%= value.attributes.message %></td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a id="voteUp" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" rel="<%= value.attributes.objectId%> "><img width="30" src="img/appbar.thumbs.up.png"/></a></td>
                                    <td width="30">
                                        +<%= value.attributes.thumbsup %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a id="voteDown" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" rel=" <%= value.attributes.objectId %> "><img width="30" src="img/appbar.thumbs.down.png"/></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="30">
                                        -<%= value.attributes.thumbsdown %>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <%  });
```

In my DB on Parse the objectId is show but i only can access to username, message, thumbsup, thumbsdown.

[Here is my jsfiddle with my complete home.html and app.js](http://jsfiddle.net/Irvollo/y3RdB/)

Comment: Yes, it is inside. I'll try to fix the Jsfiddle Asap. Thnk you

Comment: `_.template(this.template)` returns a *function*, not a piece of HTML. You get HTML by saying `_.tempate(tmpl, some_object_with_data)` or, more common, `var t = _.template(t); var h = t(this.model.toJSON())` or `t(this.collection.toJSON())`. Saying `x.html(_.template(tmpl))` sort of pretends to work because you can give [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) a function and it will execute it for you (but it won't give the function the arguments it is expecting).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should debug the backbone/parse collection layer and first determine what TYPE reference you are dealing with??

attributes OR objects at the level of entries in the backbone collection

The answer to that determines how you get backbone to unwrap the individual collection entries.

Note [this thread](https://parse.com/questions/javascript-get-objectid) remembering that parse referents can be a little finicky regarding the valueOf(objectId).

If you are getting other field values OK from the target class and the objectId is the only one with bug, then this is definitely the issue.